# error 500 for the redirection 301

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

i'm a siteweb online with pages already indexed, I just to change a few links and I would like to make a *redirect 301* but it gives me *error 500*. I have a try a lot of average but I succeeded not. I want your help.

**It's my htaccess file:**

```
######### Generated by Lwspanel #########
######### Ne pas modifier / Don't touch #########


Order Allow,Deny
Allow From All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow From All

Redirect 301 /unlock-alcatel-ot-android-generic-phone.html"
"http://alldeviceunlock.com/Unlock-alcatel/Unlock-alcatel-OT-one-touch.html





######### End Generated by Lwspanel #########
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is more simple than that, and it appears you have some double quotes that are out of place.

```
Redirect 301 /oldfile.htm /newfile.htm
```

So if that's the syntax just do this **edited with absolute path**

```
Redirect 301 /Unlock-alcatel/Unlock-alcatel-OT-one-touch.html http://alldeviceunlock.com/Unlock-alcatel/Unlock-alcatel-OT-one-touch.html
```

Comment: it still works not,always the error message 500 @webjuju

Comment: please remove all the other lines from your htaccess and only use this one

Comment: Now it no longer displays error 500 but the redirection is not done @webjuju

Comment: I tested this line and it worked, but you know, i actually had to add the other path in (because I added a directory "test" from the document root).   **Redirect 301 /test/unlock-alcatel-ot-android-generic-phone.html http://alldeviceunlock.com/Unlock-alcatel/Unlock-alcatel-OT-one-touch.html** - are you sure that the call to unlock-alcatel-ot-android-generic-phone.html is at the document root or is it in a sub directory to your main site?

Comment: It's the full link alcatel,it's very long http://alldeviceunlock.com/unlock-lanix-huawei-alcatel-iphone-zte-pantech-doro-vodafone-motorola-avvio-blackberry/alcatel-ot-metropcs-5020t-7040n-v860-tracfone-pixi3-idol3-768-popc1-ot-871a-onetouch/unlock-alcatel-ot-android-generic-phone.html

Comment: http://alldeviceunlock.com/Unlock-alcatel/Unlock-alcatel-OT-one-touch.html it's the new link alcatel @webjuju

Comment: i've edited the solution to include the absolute path for you

Comment: I just contacted technicians at lws, I think the problem is at lws . thank you very much for your help @webjuju